# What is XRPC, how do I use it

Tags: web-services

I am trying to connect to Thomson Reuters Researcher ID service using XRPC.

My questions are as follows:

1) What is XRPC? 
2) What do I need to do to send the appropriate data

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `XML-RPC`. If I'm mistaken, then you should say so, and please post a linnk to the "XRPC" that you're asking about.

Comment: I think it is XML-RPC - they finally sent me their docs. They had written XRPC on their website and I was trying to work what that was. Given that Thomson Reuters is a reasonable size company I didn't think it was possible for them to simply make a mistake, but I think that's what might have happened.

Comment: I had the exact same question right down to the service you are connecting to a found this answer top of google... wierd

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually its not a typo. XRPC is similar to XML-RPC, but not the same. XRPC is a protocol invented in 2003 at the Institute for Scientific Information, which was acquired by Thomson. Thomson later became Thomson-Reuters.

An example request will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<request xmlns="http://www.isinet.com/xrpc41">
   <fn name="APICall1"><!-- parameters --></fn>
   <fn name="APICall2"><!-- parameters --></fn>
       :
   <fn name="APICallN"><!-- parameters --></fn>
</request>
```

And the response is similar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response xmlns="http://www.isinet.com/xrpc41">
   <fn name="APICall1" rc="OK"><!-- return value --></fn>
   <fn name="APICall2" rc="OK"><!-- return value --></fn>
       :
   <fn name="APICallN" rc="ErrorCode"><!-- error --></fn>
</response>
```

The requests/responses will be populated by data elements like

```
<val>, <list>, <map>,
```

Answer (score 2):

`XML-RPC` is the protocol from which the SOAP protocol was created. It has largely been superseded by SOAP.

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml-rpc for many question on this site on the same subject, also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-rpc and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml-rpc.

Comment: SOAP did evolve from XML-RPC but did not supercede it. In the non-Windows world, people tend to choose XML-RPC rather than SOAP because of its simplicity. Of course, even more people choose REST, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

See specification for this protocol http://search.isiknowledge.com/esti/docs/isi_xrpc41.html

Comment: Specification now at http://services.thomsoninnovation.com/ip-webservices/xrpc-demo/docs/isi_xrpc41.html